# Remote Access (via thin client, etc.) with sound?

Tags: windows, remote, thin-client

I'd like to be able to have folks on Macs and with iOS devices access our Windows programs.

I've seen a variety of services that web-enable a Windows app. The latest I've seen is Graphon.

I'm looking for something that would allow the client:

- Run on Windows, Mac, iOs (iPad, iPhone)
- Would include sound (so that the client hears the audio)
- Ideally would include microphone/recording input as well.